# jQuery or AngularJS Ajax "POST" request to server using code below however do not sending param data to server.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, iis

"POST" request to server using code below

however do not sending param data to server.

I tried jQuery Way and

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: baseUrl,
  type:'post',
  data: 'userId=userabcd&passwd=abcd1234',

});

request.done(function( msg ) {
  console.log(msg);
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

AngularJS Way.

```
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : baseUrl,
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },  
        data    : 'userId=userabcd&passwd=abcd1234'
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.log(data);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(config);

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log(data);

    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

but both are not sending "POST" query to server.

what am i doing wrong

please help.

server information

```
Mircrosoft/IIS8.0, ASP
```

Comment: How do you know it's not sending the post?  Did you step through the code?  Did you receive some sort of error?

Comment: @DavidL  Hi, I tried to create account or checking account using id and password but it only creates empty value. Is it possible because of server problem?

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console to see the requests and responses.

Comment: the server was block the request. T.T thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your server-side code it is difficult to say if that is a problem. The JS you have presented generally looks okay. You say that it runs without errors but fails to produce the expected results on the server. So I suggest you add the server-side code.

Both cases accept `data` as an object rather that a string which is generally more convenient. (avoids having to deal with encoding characters yourself)

For example:

```
data: {userId:'userabcd', passwd:'abcd1234'},
```

Have a read of the the documentation for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: jQuery will convert it to the serialize form for you `It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.` [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). But yes, the object form is often more convenient.

Comment: @Bob the server was block the request. T.T thank you for your answer.